# FXML minHeight & minWidth attributs ignored?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, window-resize, minimum-size

How can I set a minimum size to my window ? I try to set the `minHeight` `minWidth` value but I can still resize the Window under this values with the mouse.

Here is my FXML root pane:

```xml
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane"
        minHeight="200" minWidth="400" prefHeight="600" prefWidth="800"
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="simulation.Simulation_Controller">
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do so you have to set the `minHeight` and `minWidth` of your `Stage`.

Somewhere in your java code...:

Example:

```
...
yourStage.setMinHeight(480);
yourStage.setMinWidth(640);
...
```

Comment: Why? Please link to documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple, working solution:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/your/layout.fxml"));

stage.setMinWidth(root.minWidth(-1));
stage.setMinHeight(root.minHeight(-1));
```

This sets the minimum size of your stage to the values defined in the top-level element of the FXML-File, or 0 if they are not defined.

Comment: This should be the default with JavaFX. I can't understand why it isn't the case.